# Buildout-aware Python autocompletion for Sublime Text

Tags: python, plone, sublimetext, buildout

Are there any tricks how one could make Sublime Text's Python autocompletion aware off all eggs from buildout's [eggs] section

E.g. grab the same sys.path as in Plone's generated `bin/instance` command and expose them to Sublime's auto-completion. You could easily auto-complete imports and stuff after this.

A preferable solution would be

- Have special `bin/sublime` command generated by buildout
- This command would open `src/` folder as Sublime text (project?) with all necessary environment variables and stuff set

Other solutions / ideas welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check http://pypi.python.org/pypi/corneti.recipes.codeintel/0.1.3

This is even easier than Martin's solution, I use it together with omelette with a part like this in my development.cfg buildout

```
[codeintel]
recipe = corneti.recipes.codeintel
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
extra-paths =
    ${omelette:location}
```

Comment: I want to generate .codeintel under src/ so that Sublime file browser sees only the relevant files... src/ which you are editing. Though if omelette is not in the project path CMD + P go anyware does not seem to work. Will investigate the matters.

Comment: The recipe has receive update 0.2.0 with some enhancements I did: https://github.com/fabiocorneti/corneti.recipes.codeintel

Answer (score 4):

I, like Martin Aspelli, use the [SublimeCodeIntel plugin](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel); together with collective.recipe.omelette this fills all my code-completion needs. Martin blogged about his setup, including a little script that sets up the CodeIntel configuration file for you:

http://www.martinaspeli.net/articles/sublime-text-2-for-zope-and-plone

Comment: As a side note, I have a very good experience with ST2's [SublimeRope plugin](https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimeRope) for Python autocompletion.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in using SublimeRope instead, you can add something like this to your .ropeproject/config.py:

```
import os
import glob
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../buildout-cache/eggs/*.egg')):
    prefs.add('python_path', path)
```

Those buildout methods are quite fancy though!

Answer (score 1):

This is another buildout recipe [plone.recipe.sublimetext](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.sublimetext/) that supports `SublimeText 3` with one of the best autocomplete plugin [SublimeJEDI](https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI), SublimeLinter (flake8, pylint).

This recipe will create buildout specific sublime project file with all paths included (i.e all eggs path for Jedi). Simple use case could be

```
[buildout]
eggs =
# All eggs here
parts = 
    sublimetext
#   other parts here
[sublimetext]
recipe = plone.recipe.sublimetext
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
jedi-enabled = True
sublimelinter-enabled = True
sublimelinter-flake8-enabled = True
```

Comment: a new release is coming up, making it possible to use the omelette as a basis for jedi completion and go-to-definition.